# Bicycle noise when pedaling

Tags: noise

When I pedal my bike, it make a very loud noise.

I put a video so you can hear what it sound like:

**https://streamable.com/e5jl8**

Further info:   I tried all these steps to try to fix the problem and nothing worked:

- degreased the chain with a degreaser and cleaned with soap and hot water.
- lubricated the chain
- replaced the bottom bracket with a new one
- greased around the bearings
- greased the pedals.

Do you guys suggest another thing I can do ?

Problem solved: 
The noise was coming from the right pedal, i changed both pedals and the noise is now gone.
Thanks for help guys

Comment: Most likely the pedal bearings.  But could be the bottom bracket bearings.

Comment: Please add a textual description and a photo to your post. Once that video has been deleted your post is useless for future readers.

Comment: I re upload the video

Comment: I note that the bike is exceptionally clean, leading one to suspect that it has been washed with a hose, or perhaps "power washed".  It's very easy, when using a hose, to accidentally wash the lube out of bearings.

Comment: I wonder if it couldn't be the FD cage rubbing the plastic chainring guard.

Answer (score 2):

If you can diagnose exactly where the noise is coming from, it will be easier to know what you need to service/replace. It sounds like the squeak is periodic with the crank turning around (as opposed to the chain or the wheel), so that would suggest that it is a problem with the crank, bottom bracket, or pedals. Try inspecting and turning the pedals and crank independently and see if you can narrow it down from there.

If the grease around the bearings washes out, the bearings can deform or break or become loose, and sometimes that will lead to a problem like that. Chances are the easiest way to fix it is to just replace whatever is making that noise.

Answer (score 2):

You have a nasty squeak which means something is not lubricated. The squeak is synced with crank rotations so it's very likely bottom bracket bearings, chain or pedal bearings rather than the rear wheel.

Start by cleaning and lubing the chain properly. That's easy and accessible. There are plenty of tutorials online that show you how to do it.

If that does not make a difference, the bottom bracket bearings probably need to be looked at. Depending on the type you have on your bike they can be disassembled, cleaned and re-greased, or replaced completely.

Comment: In addition to BB or pedals, it might be the front derailleur hitting the chainwheel.  If it goes away when you shift, that's it.  (Or maybe you need new knees).

Comment: I've never heard a chain create a squeak like that.  Most often I've found it to be the pedals, but it can be other odd things.

Comment: Advice to clean and lube chain is to rule it out as a problem, and it’s not going to hurt anything

Comment: i did clean and lubricated the chain but it didn't solved the issue